# jquery not working in .net 2.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net-2.0

I have vs 2005 and .net 2.0 ...my code is as follows:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Edw.aspx.cs"     Inherits="BenefitsPaymentSystem.Edw" MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master" %>




<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" ID="EDWContent" runat="server">
<asp:Panel ID="pnlSearchEDW" GroupingText="Search Enterprise Dataware House " runat="server" CssClass="panel">

    <asp:RadioButtonList Visible="false" ForeColor="midnightblue" ID="rblEDWSearchOtpions" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="10" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblEDWSearchOtpions_Change" AutoPostBack="true" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="Client Serach" Value="Client"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Program Area Search" Value="Program"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
   <a id="lnkSearch" href="#" onclick="slidein();return false;">Begin Client Search</a>  
   <br />
   <br />
</asp:Panel>
<br />
<br />

<div id="clientdiv">
<asp:Panel id="pnlClientSearch" runat="server" CssClass="panel" Visible="true" GroupingText="Client Search">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="textCell">Case# and Suffix</td>
            <td class="dataCell">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCaseAndSuffix" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="textCell">SSN</td>
            <td class="dataCell">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSSN" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="textCell">CIN</td>
            <td class="dataCell">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCIN" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>

            <td class="textCell">First/Last Name</td>
            <td class="dataCell">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>

        </tr>


    </table>
</asp:Panel>
</div>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlProgramAreaSearch" runat="server" CssClass="panel" Visible="false" GroupingText="Program Area Search">
<table>
    <tr>
    <td class="textCell"></td>
    <td class="dataCell">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="dddPrgramSearchList" runat="server" CssClass="ddl" Width="150pt">
        <asp:ListItem Text="PA" Value="PA"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="NPA" Value="NPA"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="MA" Value="MA"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="ALL" Value="ALL"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    </tr>

</table>
</asp:Panel>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {
alert('');
});

function slidein()
{
alert('');

    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlClientSearch').fadeIn('slow',3000);
    //$('#clientdiv').fadeIn('slow');
    //retunr false;

}
</script>
```

The fadeIn is not working...altough the jquery document ready is being callledd....
I dont have any script errors ....I want the panel to slide in...I aslo tried out the slidein as well....

Comment: I don't see a reference to the jQuery library in your code.  Does it exist outside this example block?

Comment: yes it is in the master page...its definitely included as document.ready generates the alert....if it wrent included ....document ready wouldn't have worked

Answer (score 1):

either remove the href="#" attribute from your link, or "return false" at the end of your slidein() function to prevent navigating away from the page.

also check out http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ to see how to prevent default event behavior the jQuery way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#lnkSearch').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        slidein();
    });
});
```

Comment: i returned false...it doesnt work and it was giving the script error because i typed the wrong spelling for return....but it still doesnt work...???

Comment: ok... then consider changing the way you're binding your click event to the anchor.  the preferred way is to handle it via jquery in your document ready function.  you can see an example in the above link.  i'll also edit my post to show you how.

Comment: no hope...i did what you did...removed the onclick from the  "a" tag but it still doesnt work...just to see if it os working added an alert inside the call back of the binding function in document ready function

Answer (score 0):

Not sure without looking at more code, but two things I would try-

First, in a script debugger, verify that the clientID of the panel is indeed ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlClientSearch.

Second, also in a script debugger, verify that $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlClientSearch) resolves to a jquery object.

Comment: it is the id...verifired throgh firefox...but i dont know what you mean by the second statement...I am editing my code and including the whole page...so tis clear what I am doing...plz help

Comment: In your code above, I noticed you added an alert to the slideIn method.  Is that alert firing?

Answer (score 0):

Return false in the event handler to keep the link from reloading the page:

```
<a id="lnkSearch" href="#" onclick="slidein();return false;">
```

You can also hook up the event handler in the jQuery code instead, and use the `preventDefault` method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#lnkSearch').click(function(e){
    slidein();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: no hope...i did what you did...removed the onclick from the "a" tag but it still doesnt work...just to see if it os working added an alert inside the call back of the binding function in document ready function –

Comment: @abbas: Your `fadeIn` call looks strange; you have two different settings for durations. Try using only a single setting for duration: `.fadeIn('slow')`.